# How to theoretically raise the temperature of a thermal state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, temperature, harmonic-oscillator

I am currently studying thermal states of coupled harmonic oscillators and was wondering, how can I theoretically raise the temperature of a thermal state? I.e. how does the unitary transformation have to look so that the temperature can be increased? Is it even possible to do this via unitaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest theoretical way to change the temperature of a thermal state is obviously to change the value of the parameter, but evidently this is not the question. The question is whether one can change the temperature of a thermal state by a unitary process.

In a closed system, a unitary process would maintain the purity of the state. Since the temperature is linked to the purity of the state, a unitary process would not be able to change the temperature of a thermal state in a closed system.

In an open system where the thermal state is coupled to another state like a thermal bath, then it would be possible to formulate a unitary process that operates on the combination of the two state to convert some energy from one state to the other and thus change the temperature of the thermal state.

Comment: Could you perhaps, expand on your answer a bit? I find especially the last part intriguing. How can one implement a unitary which raises the temperature of one system when it is coupled to say a battery or so.

Comment: You would need to specify the details of the subsystems and how they are coupled. It is perhaps better to formulate that as a new question.

Comment: Shouldn't this be possible by varying a parameter of the Hamiltonian cyclically?